# when I try to upload an image on firestore I get the url but it is not stored in the firestore database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, image-upload

```
  const CreatePost = async () => {
    if (imageUpload == null) return;
    const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/`);
    uploadBytes(imageRef, imageUpload).then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(imageRef).then((url) => {
        setImageUrl(url);
        console.log(url);
      });
    });
```

console.log(url) Works and gives me the correct url but it is not stored in firestore

[image]

Answer (score 0):

React useState hook is asynchronous. So, it won't have the URL that you are setting at the time when you're using it. Use the useEffect hook and add your state in the dependence array, and you will always get the updated value.